# Typescript not allowing a union type in an array

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I'm having trouble understanding discriminated unions in typescript in the context of an array. Using the example from the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), I would expect the below to be perfectly valid.

```js
interface Circle {
  kind: "circle";
  radius: number;
}
 
interface Square {
  kind: "square";
  sideLength: number;
}
 
type Shape = Circle | Square;

const getShapes = (): Shape[] => {
    const data = [
        { kind: "circle", radius: 1 },
        { kind: "square", sideLength: 3}
    ]
    return data;
}
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMLCggNig3gKGWQGtQATALmQCIENsJqBuQ5KOM4AVwGcqQuAWwBG0FgF9C+UJFiIUAZQCOXOFDytSISjR4q1jFkR7AyEADIQQAczAALfkNFQJUsAE8ADortxvyAF40ehxkAB9kZVV1FnwEAHsQHjBkawgwBV9vHkDkAAoASipMvwgAbQBdQIA+ZAIiIgSklLI4MDhcstYGhtwScipaEMYAGjYObj5kAEZkcRHunrr+7UG9aNHkEzNLG3sqAGZJHorF9TAuKBBkVvaJIA)

My understanding is this is saying "a Shape must be either a Circle or a Square".

Instead it gives this error:

> Type '({ kind: string; radius: number; sideLength?: undefined; } | { kind: string; sideLength: number; radius?: undefined; })[]' is not assignable to type 'Shape[]'.
> Type '{ kind: string; radius: number; sideLength?: undefined; } | { kind: string; sideLength: number; radius?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Shape'.
> Type '{ kind: string; radius: number; sideLength?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Shape'.
> Type '{ kind: string; radius: number; sideLength?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Square'.
> Types of property 'kind' are incompatible.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"square"'.

I'm specifically confused about seeing `kind: string` as how typescript interpreted that, when it matches the literal. Based on how I'm reading the docs, this seems like a perfectly valid use for a union

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When presented with a variable declaration `const data = ⋯` with no [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables), TypeScript *infers* the type of the variable from the initializer, based on heuristic inference rules that work well in a wide range of scenarios.  It does not currently have the ability to defer that and "look ahead" to see how the variable is used later.  Given

```
const data = [
  { kind: "circle", radius: 1 },
  { kind: "square", sideLength: 3 }
];
```

the compiler infers

```
const data: ({
    kind: string;
    radius: number;
    sideLength?: undefined;
} | {
    kind: string;
    sideLength: number;
    radius?: undefined;
})[]
```

because that's what inference rules say to do. In particular, string literal properties get widened to `string`, since it's very common for people to modify the values of properties.  The compiler does not see that you intend to return `data` as `Shape[]`, so it doesn't know that you intend for the `kind` property to have string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  By the time you `return data` is encountered, it is too late.  The type of `data` is already set.

---

If you want to fix this you should either annotate `data` like `const data: Shape[] = ⋯`, or you could use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) on the initializer to give the compiler the context it is missing:

```
const getShapes = (): Shape[] => {
  const data = [
    { kind: "circle", radius: 1 },
    { kind: "square", sideLength: 3 }
  ] satisfies Shape[]
  return data;
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMLCggNig3gKGWQGtQATALmQCIENsJqBuQ5KOM4AVwGcqQuAWwBG0FgF98+UJFiIUAZQCOXOFDytSISjR4q1jFkR7AyEADIQQAczAALfkNFQJUsAE8ADortxvyAF40ehxkAB9kZVV1FnwEAHsQHjBkawgwBV9vHkDkAAoASipMvwgAbQBdQIA+ZAIiBKSUsjgwOFyy1iJcEnIqWhDGABo2Dm4+ZABGZHEhrrre7X69aOHkEzNLG3sqAGYZ1iqeVuAeGGAIHJLvStZ1MC4oEGQWtokgA)

Answer (score 1):

Inference is having a hard time to infer the type of `data` :

```
const data: ({
    kind: string;
    radius: number;
    sideLength?: undefined;
} | {
    kind: string;
    sideLength: number;
    radius?: undefined;
})[]
```

Enforcing the type fixes your issue : `const data:Shape[]`